# GCP Cloud Build trigger 'Push new tag' doesn't work properly

Tags: github, google-cloud-platform, tags, cloud, google-cloud-build

I tried to configure a GCP cloud build trigger to automatically trigger a new build when a new tag is pushed to a github repository.

However, even if a tag is created and pushed, the build won't trigger at all.

My tag is automatically created and pushed from [semantic-release plugin](https://github.com/semantic-release/github) after a successful merge.

[Trigger configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/63cF5.png)

I'm sure it's the correct repository, and the regex should accept any tag. There is no files filters.

I have another trigger with type 'Push to a branch' which works correctly on the same repo, so i don't know what i could have miss here.

Any ideas?

**Edit 26/1/2023:**

Tried to push a tag without the semantic release, which doesn't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i had the same issue , to resolve it you need to :

- [Reformat](https://github.com/semantic-release/git#usage) release commit message ( remove [skip ci] from the message commit to be more Precisely)
- lunch a new build to generate new github tag if you use cloud build for it otherwise you need to remove the commit that contains [skip ci] and generate the tag manually

After that your cloudbuild job with push new tag trigger should start

Comment: Thanks !! Changing '[skip ci]' did the trick. Was a sneaky one !